# Text too long for the cell?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, formatting, vertical-alignment, rotating

I am doing this table, but my the phrases are out of the limits of the cells. How can I adjust them in two or three lines instead of one?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{1.2cm}|}
        \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{University} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Year 1996} &  \multirow{3}{*}{Total}  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Year 2010} & \multirow{3}{*}{Total} \\
        \cline{2-5} \cline{7-10}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Students} & \multirow{2}{*}{Docentes universitarios} & \multirow{2}{*}{Personal administrativo y de servicio} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Students} & \multirow{2}{*}{Docente universitario} & \multirow{2}{*}{Personal administrativo y de servicio}&  \\
        \cline{2-3} \cline{7-8}
        & Pre grade & Post grade &  &  &  & Pre grade & Post grade &  & &  \\
        \hline
        National University & 3225 & 268 & 453 & 498 & 4434 & 4903 &976 & 445 & 802 & 7126 \\
   \hline

    \end{tabular}

    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

As I am using `\multirow{...}` and `|p{Xcm}|`, the words are not centered, how can I fixed this?

Comment: It is good that you've posted some code but a complete minimal example would be more helpful than a mere fragment. Could you complete it so we can copy-paste-compile it to see the problem?

Comment: You can use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}` in the tabular specification before the column you want centred if you load the package **array**. Note that if you use `\multirow` with `*`, the width is set to the natural width of the content. If you want a smaller width, you need to specify it.

Comment: @cfr: It can be quite tedious to use multiple `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{...}`. Perhaps, it's better to recommend the usual `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{...}` stuff

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That's what I actually did once I'd got code to work with ;).

Answer (score 1):

This stays as close as possible to your original table. I don't recommend doing it this way, but it works. I fiddled with the text block height to get it to fit, since I'm assuming it fits in your actual page. I've also faked hyphenation because I wasn't sure which language to tell Babel. (Obviously, you should take my hyphenation points out and let Babel do its thing in your real document.)

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

defines a new column type, `C{<width>}` which is just like `p` but centred. If you want vertical centring as well, substitute `m` for `p`.

```
\renewcommand\multirowsetup{\centering}
```

This alters the default formatting for `\multirow` content from `\raggedright` to `\centering`.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scale=.825]{geometry}% without this you'll get US letter paper layout on A4
\usepackage{rotfloat,array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{multirow}
\renewcommand\multirowsetup{\centering}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{tabular}{|C{5cm}|C{1.2cm}|C{1.2cm}|C{1.7cm}|C{1.7cm}|C{1.2cm}|C{1.2cm}|C{1.2cm}|C{1.7cm}|C{1.7cm}|C{1.2cm}|}
  \hline
  \multirow{6}{*}{University} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Year 1996} &  \multirow{6}{*}{Total}  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Year 2010} & \multirow{6}{*}{Total} \\
  \cline{2-5} \cline{7-10}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Students} & \multirow{5}{1.7cm}{Docentes universit\-arios} & \multirow{5}{1.7cm}{Personal administrativo y de servicio} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Students} & \multirow{5}{1.7cm}{Docente universit\-ario} & \multirow{5}{1.7cm}{Personal administrativo y de servicio}&  \\
  \cline{2-3} \cline{7-8}
  & \multirow{3}{12mm}{Pre grade} & \multirow{3}{12mm}{Post grade} &  &  &  & \multirow{3}{12mm}{Pre grade} & \multirow{3}{12mm}{Post grade} &  & &  \\
  &&&&&&&&&&\\
  &&&&&&&&&&\\
  &&&&&&&&&&\\
  \hline
  National University & 3225 & 268 & 453 & 498 & 4434 & 4903 &976 & 445 & 802 & 7126 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image: tweaked table]

However, this is not the best way to set tabular material. In particular, the use of vertical rules is not recommended and some horizontal rules should be heavier than others. In addition, more spacing is needed so that cell contents do not look squashed and are easier to read.

**booktabs** has a good discussion of best practice for typesetting professional-quality tabular material. It is worth reading. Even if it is occasionally perhaps a little overly dogmatic, it is a very useful antidote to the kind of formatting encouraged by word processors!

I would think about something more like this:

[image: rethinking the table]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scale=.825]{geometry}% without this you'll get US letter paper layout on A4
\usepackage{rotfloat,array,calc,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{multirow}
\renewcommand\multirowsetup{\centering}
\newlength\mylength
\setlength\mylength{20mm+\tabcolsep}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
  \begin{tabular}{C{5cm}*{4}{C{10mm}}*{2}{C{15mm}}*{2}{C{22.5mm}}*{2}{C{10mm}}}
  \toprule
  \multirow{3}*{University} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Students} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Docentes} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Personal administrativo} &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{\mylength}{Total}}  \\
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Pre grade} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Post grade} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{universitarios} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{y de servicio} &&\\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-9} \cmidrule(lr){10-11}
  & 1996 & 2010  & 1996 & 2010  & 1996 & 2010 & 1996 & 2010 & 1996 & 2010  \\
  \midrule
  National University & 3225 & 268 & 453 & 498 & 4434 & 4903 &976 & 445 & 802 & 7126 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose this solution, based an the `makecell` package, which allows for line breaks in cells, and `booktabs`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{booktabs, array, multirow, caption, makecell, tabularx}
 \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setcellgapes{1pt}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

    \begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\renewcommand\tabcolsep{4pt}
\makegapedcells
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textheight}{p{2.8cm}cc > {}XXcccXXc}
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Year 1996} & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Year 2010} & \\
    \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](lr){2-5} \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](lr){7-10}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Students} & && & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Students} & & & \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){7-8}
    \textbf{University} & \makecell{Pre\\ grade} & \makecell{Post\\ grade} &\makecell{Docentes\\ universitarios} & \multirowcell{-3}[-1.4ex]{Personal \\administrativo\\ y de servicio} & \textbf{Total} & \makecell{Pre\\ grade} & \makecell{Post\\ grade} & \makecell{Docente \\universitario} & \multirowcell{-3}[-1.4ex]{Personal\\ administrativo\\ y de servicio} & \textbf{Total} \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    National University & 3225 & 268 & 453 & 498 & 4434 & 4903 &976 & 445 & 802 & 7126 \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}

    \end{document}
```

[image]